# Protect partition from formatting

Tags: windows, linux, protection, deletion

How can i protect my Linux and Windows partitions from being wiped,from a windows installation CD,with password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if your drive has such functionality internally built-in (which circumvents all OS and User privileges) or if you are using some sort of hardware-level lock. Other than this, it is impossible to stop a user who has both physical access and admin privileges from accessing/formatting data on your drive.

You can however, using software like Gparted, hide the drive which will prevent from writing/formatting in normal usage but I don't think it will help if someone is using a windows installation CD (or some bootable partition software).

Comment: Immagine someone had stole my laptop.I have a geolocalization system based on a SSh daemon listening,with Da software like Dydns orNo-IP to retrieve the IP of the thief that powers-up my laptop.I donn't want that the thief had the wipe-all ability and lose  my laptop for ever.

Comment: Like I suggested, best thing you can do is hide the drives and hope you can find him before he finds that drive.
It also depends on your luck to whether they person who robbed you has the technical expertise.

Comment: @QuickBow Do you want to protect your data or trace your stolen laptop? Protect => Backup, Trace => build in GPS Tracker with GSM

Answer (score 2):

If you have an SSD hard disk, you might be able to use low-level routines to mark cells containing your linux partition as [dead](https://www.blackhat.com/us-13/archives.html#Thomas1)<sup>†</sup>.  Without some hacking, these cells will then be opaque to other operating systems.

<sup>† [Hiding @ Depth - Exploring, Subverting and Breaking NAND Flash memory](https://www.blackhat.com/us-13/archives.html#Thomas1)</sup>

Comment: Have you any link about this tecnique?

Comment: Yes ... follow the link from the word "dead" to its corresponding Blackhat talk.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your system from evil boot devices by setting a bios password and make you hard drive the default boot device. Problem is that is someone can insert a boot device he most likely can also reset your bios or unplug your hard drive. You can lock and glue your device together to make physical attaches more difficult but that will only buy you some time.

If you really want to protect your hard drive from being delete there is only one advisable way:

**Backup** that drive regularly!

Also don't forget to *encrypt your backup*.

**Tracking**: In respond to your comment above where you suggest that your goal is, not to protect the hard drive, but to track you laptop. Buy a GPS Tracker with GSM with a USB power connector and glue it inside.

Comment: @AbbasJavanJafari "Resetting a bios password is easier than using a bootable CD"
I guess there is nothing more to say.

Comment: BIOS passwords may be enough to prevent access from a typical thief. For example, to unlock a Dell mobile BIOS password you must verify ownership before Dell will release the challenge response. On desktops it is usually as simple as moving a jumper, laptops are generally designed differently for this exact reason. Of course someone may have access to the OEM's tools or reverse their algorithm, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: You have failed to understand the problem mentioned by the author. There are many ways to bypass this and format the hard drive. In some laptops you can physically jump the BIOS using a paperclip or as you said yourself remove the hard drive. Backing up doesn't help, he wants to prevent drive formatting in case the device gets stolen so he can use security daemons to track the laptop.

Comment: Backup answers the question. My edit about tracking answers OP comment to your answer. Hiding tracking software on the hard drive is difficult to impossible. You might hide it in a firmware or additional hardware you place inside like a GPS tracker.

Comment: I know and I said the same thing. There are hardware-level protections you can implement but in terms of software protections, if an adversary has physical access and enough time, it is near impossible to stop him. But backing up does not help you stop an adversary who has stolen your device. If your main goal is to recover lost data then yes, backing up is necessary and effective.